# Updating particular records from a PageBlocktable

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

I have been trying to display a list of records of a custom object on the visualforce page along with the checkboxes, using a wrapper class in order to be able to update only those which are checked, but the functionality is not functioning properly. It is updating records even if I do not select the checkbox and click on Update Button. Can anyone please help? Below is my code :

Visualforce Page :

```
<apex:page controller="TransactionUpdateController">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function selectAllCheckboxes(obj,receivedInputID){
        var inputCheckBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(var i=0; i<inputCheckBox.length; i++){
            if(inputCheckBox[i].id.indexOf(receivedInputID)!=-1){
                inputCheckBox[i].checked = obj.checked;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock title="Transaction List">
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Transactions">
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
     <apex:outputLabel value="Start Date" />
     <apex:inputField value="{!objTransaction1.Date__c}"/>
 </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
 <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
     <apex:outputLabel value="End Date" />
     <apex:inputField value="{!objTransaction2.Date__c}"/>
 </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
 <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
 <apex:commandButton value="Display Transactions" action="{!displayListofTransactions}" reRender="TransactionsTable"/>
 </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

 <br/>
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!wrapperTempList}" var="t" title="All Transactions" id="TransactionsTable" >
    <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">
            <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId')"/>
        </apex:facet>
        <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!t.checked}" id="inputId"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column value="{!t.objTransaction.Name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!t.objTransaction.Date__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!t.objTransaction.Description__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!t.objTransaction.Status__c}"/>
    <apex:column headerValue="Update Status">
        <apex:inputField value="{!t.objTransaction.Status__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">
            <apex:commandButton value="Update Transactions" action="{!saveRecords}" reRender="TransactionsTable"/>
        </apex:facet>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageblockTable>

<br/>





</apex:pageBlockSection>

</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

Apex Class :

```
public class TransactionUpdateController{

//public InnerClass lstInnerClass1 { get; set; }
//private final ApexPages.StandardController controller;
//public List<InnerClass> lstInnerClass {get;set;}
public Date startDate;
public Date endDate;
public Transactions__c objTransaction1 {get;set;}
public Transactions__c objTransaction2 {get;set;}
//public List<Transactions__c> lstTransactions{get;set;}
public List<InnerClass> wrapperTempList{get;set;}
public TransactionUpdateController() {
    if(wrapperTempList == null) {           
        wrapperTempList = new List<InnerClass>();
    }

}

/*
public List < InnerClass > getTransactionData() {
    List < InnerClass > wrapperTempList = new List < InnerClass > ();

    lstTransactions = [SELECT
                                Id,
                                Name,
                                Account__c,
                                Amount__c,
                                Approved__c,
                                Date__c,
                                Description__c,
                                Status__c,
                                Subject__c
                        FROM
                                Transactions__c

                        ORDER BY
                                Date__c Desc
                        LIMIT   
                                1000
                        ];
    if(lstTransactions.size()>0) {
        System.debug('Debug Log for lstTransactions'+lstTransactions.size());   
        for(Transactions__c objTransaction : lstTransactions) {
            wrapperTempList.add(new InnerClass(objTransaction,false));
        }
    }
    return wrapperTempList;
}
*/
public PageReference displayListofTransactions() {
    //wrapperTempList = new List<InnerClass>();
    if(wrapperTempList.size() >0){
        wrapperTempList.clear();
    }

    //startDate = objTransaction1.Date__c != null ? objTransaction1.Date__c : System.Today();
    //endDate = objTransaction1.Date__c != null ? objTransaction1.Date__c : System.Today();
    //System.debug('Debug Log for startDate'+startDate);
    //System.debug('Debug Log for endDate'+endDate);
    for(Transactions__c objTransaction : [SELECT
                                            Id,
                                            Name,
                                            Account__c,
                                            Amount__c,
                                            Approved__c,
                                            Date__c,
                                            Description__c,
                                            Status__c,
                                            Subject__c
                                    FROM
                                            Transactions__c
                                    WHERE   
                                            Date__c >:startDate
                                    AND
                                            Date__c <:endDate

                                    ORDER BY
                                            Date__c Desc
                                    LIMIT   
                                            1000
                                    ]) {
                                            wrapperTempList.add(new InnerClass(objTransaction,false));
                                    }
    return null;

}

public PageReference saveRecords() {
    List<Transactions__c> lstTransactionstoUpdate = new List<Transactions__c>();
    for(InnerClass objInnerClass : wrapperTempList) {
        if(objInnerClass.checked = true) {
            lstTransactionstoUpdate.add(objInnerClass.objTransaction);
        }
    }
    System.debug('Debug Log for Selected Records'+lstTransactionstoUpdate);
    try {
        List<Database.Saveresult> r = Database.update(lstTransactionstoUpdate,false);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        System.debug('Debug Log for exception while updating records'+ex);
    }
    return null;
}
public class InnerClass {
    public Transactions__c objTransaction{get;set;}
    public Boolean checked{get;set;}
    public InnerClass(Transactions__c t, Boolean b) {
        this.objTransaction = t;
        this.checked = b;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You've stumbled across one of the lesser known features of Apex Code: assignment within a condition (yes, this is actually legal):

```
    if(objInnerClass.checked = true) {
```

Here, you're assigning the value `true` to the `checked` variable, which then returns true for the entire condition, so it always adds the record to the list.

Instead, you should have used `==`:

```
    if(objInnerClass.checked == true) {
```

However, I recommend that you never, ever do this, because of the inherent risk you'll use `=` instead of `==` and introduce subtle bugs (as you've found out). Instead, you can directly skip the `== true`:

```
    if(objInnerClass.checked) {
```

This is easier to read and actually has better performance characteristics.